# How to setup RAID 1+0 on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I'm using the RAID 1+0 structure as described in this post: [RAID 1+0 vs RAID 0+1](https://serverfault.com/questions/166300/raid-10-vs-raid-01)

I'm at the installation screen for Ubuntu Server.  Both of my raid stripes are setup.  The screen I'm looking at now allows me to create partitions and stuff and I'm not sure how to setup the drive mirroring.  Can anyone help guide me in the right direction?

All of my hardware specs are in the other thread.

I've followed the guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

Though I'm not sure if I should be - it still fails to create the MD.

---

**update**

The configuration I have now where it won't let me create the mirrored RAID (assuming I'm doing it correctly)....

```
Serial ATA RAID isw_bcjjcifhdi_primary (stripe) - 1.0 TB Linux de
     #1 primary 988.0 GB B
     #5 logical  12.2 GB
Serial ATA RAID isw_dbgajfddgf_secondary (stripe) - 1.0 TB Linux
     #1 primary 988.0 GB B f ext4 /
     #5 logical  12.2 GB   F swap swap
```

---

**update**

the problem was that I didn't select RAID10 from the beginning.  I tried to setup dual stripes first.... oops!

---

When I go into format the partitions it won't create an Ext4 file system on the RAID.... it fails.  Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hardware RAID controller, so you don't want to set up any software RAID at all.

The RAID controller will have some sort of configuration interface (possibly through the BIOS) where you can define your arrays.

Before you even install the operating system, you will need to go into the RAID configuration and create a RAID10 array using all of your disks. Once you've done that, it will present the array as a single disk to any Operating System you install.

When you go to install your Operating System, just set it to use the whole "disk" (which is actually all of your disks together in the RAID array) and you'll be fine. The RAID controller does all the mirroring and striping for you, so you shouldn't have to configure anything RAID related in the Operating System itself.

Comment: The RAID controller is where I setup the stripes, but I didn't see any options to setup the mirroring.... I'll take another look.

Comment: If it's helpful at all, I found the manual for that RAID controller here: http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/RAID_SATA_ESB2.pdf. Make sure you chose a RAID10 level too.