# RAID 10 Setup showing 2 drives

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-raid

I have a RAID 10 (0+1) setup among 4 drives and I'm installing my OS and it's showing 2 drives.  My understanding of this structure as outlined here: [RAID 1+0 vs RAID 0+1](https://serverfault.com/questions/166300/raid-10-vs-raid-01) is that I should only be seeing a single drive.  I'm hesitant to install the OS to one of these drives when I think I should be seeing a single drive.

---

**update**

My raid controller looks like this....

```
id   name       level         strip    size       status     bootable
0    primary    RAID10(0+1)   64 KB    921.5GB    Normal     Yes
```

Below that it shows all physical disks belong to `Member Disk (0)`

---

**update**

It appears I only have the option for `RAID10(0+1)` .... dangit, why can't I get 1+0?

Comment: I am not familiar with that Intel controller.  Are you sure it isn't [fakeraid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto).  Using the software RAID may be preferable to fakeraid.

Comment: @Zordache, I checked out the ESB2 controller he's got; Intel just re-branded an Adaptec chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; it's definitely not a RAID10 if you see two drives. It's more likely two RAID1 or two RAID0 arrays. If your RAID controller has an option for RAID10, just pick that and assign the 4 drives; it should come out looking like one drive.

On a side note, why RAID 0+1? It's a better idea to do 1+0 if you have the choice.

**Edit:**
[Here's a copy of Intel's RAID Setup Guide for the ESB2 Controller](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/RAID_SATA_ESB2.pdf)

Comment: Refer to the page I linked to as to why I'm doing 0+1.

Despite seeing 2 drives, the RAID control panel is showing that all 4 drives belong to the RAID10(0+1).  But I still see 2 drives when I go to setup ubuntu server.

Comment: Do the disks belong to the same volume or 2 different volumes? If there's nothing on the disks, I'd be inclined to delete all the RAID arrays and start from scratch with another RAID10 array.

Comment: There's nothing on the disks right now, I've deleted the RAID arrays multiple times - assuming you're referring to simply deleting the raid volume.  Basically the setup I have right now is I have 4 empty drives and a raid controller.  I haven't done anything past trying to configure raid.

Comment: @Webnet, see my edit; I'd suggest deleting whatever you have now and following those directions step by step.

Comment: Chris you're right, I was trying to setup the wrong raid controller.

Thanks for that Chris!!